# Empty cookies jar in WebTestCase

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I would like to test if my cookie is set correctly in controller.

```
class RedirectControllerTest extends WebTestCase 
{   
    public function testSetCookie($lang, $id, $actionUrl) 
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', /test);
        $jar = $client->getCookieJar();
    }
}
```

Controller sets cookie, but my cookie jar in test case is empty.

Is it even possible to have access to cookies in test cases?

Answer (score 1):

Accessing cookies through the cookie jar is the way to go:

```php
/* @var \Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie $cookie */
$cookie = $client->getCookieJar()->get('foo');
```

It works in my projects. If your cookie jar is empty you're most likely not setting the cookie properly. Remember you need to return the response you set the cookie on.